# Visual Studio debugging - "Flag Points"?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, plugins, breakpoints

I'm looking for a feature - wondering if it exists in some 3rd party plug-in or something.  Basically what I'm thinking of would be something you could set up that would be like a break point, only it doesn't stop execution.  Merely alters the appearance (changes color maybe) of the break point when that line of code is executed.  It could even use a counter, so you can see at any given moment how many times that line has been run.

Basically where it would come in handy is when you get an exception thrown in such a way that your stack trace is less than informative (maybe error handling is handled in a separate thread, or maybe different packages have different optimization settings so not all are directly debuggable), you can then look and easily see which lines of code have executed, and very quickly narrow down the source of the exception.  I'm aware that you can put a hit-count on regular break points, and you can just set the value really high to stop it from actually breaking at these points, but break point counters aren't immediately visible, so you have to hover over them one by one to see where execution stopped.  This would provide an immediate trail leading right to the point where things went wrong - like following the missing dots to figure out where Pacman is.

I'm just curious if anyone's seen a plug-in out there that can do this sort of thing or if I'm just dreaming here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using tracepoints? You add them through the normal breakpoint menu, but you need to select `When hit...` option:

[image]

In the window that should appear you have few system variables available that will describe who called your tracepoint - let's add `, hits: {hits++}` to the defaults (I marked with red the important parts):

[image]

Finally define a hits variable in the class where you placed your tracepoint:

```
class Program
{
#if DEBUG
    private static int hits;
#endif
...
```

Run your code under VS debugger and you should see in your Immediate/Output (depending on your settings) logs like the ones below:

```
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 1
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 2
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 3
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 4
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 5
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 6
Function: Program.Main(), Thread: 0x1604 Main Thread, hits: 7
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: +1 because I can see that's it might help for this type of thing, but we already have systems in place to print messages to console within the code, so it only adds a little bit - problem is that the code produces such a vast quantity of output that it's quickly pushed out of the console buffer.  Some sort of visible flag in the code itself is what I'm really looking for, if it exists.